# Auto complete text boxes from datagrid - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-ce

I am beginner and I am developing an application in Windows CE 6 in Visual Studio 2008. I have datagrid contains user details, some text boxes are placed below the grid to edit the user details. Now I want to fill these text boxes when user clicks on the data grid. I have tried every thing and results from interent are based on "datagridview". What I need is How to fill textboxes from a **DATAGRID** not **DATAGRIDVIEW** !!

This is what I have tried

```
int row = dgShowData.CurrentCell.RowNumber;
int col = dgShowData.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber;
txtNameEdit.Text = string.Format("{0}", dgShowData[row, col]);
```

I know this code is wrong, because it fill textbox-Name Edit from the current row and current cell. I want fill all the textboxes from the current row. Someone please help me! I AM IN DEEP TROUBLE NOW!!!

Comment: Not sure but is there something like dgShowData.CurrentCell.Text or dgShowData.CurrentCell.Value??

Comment: Show us how you fill your data grid

Comment: Datagrid is filled from database. SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dgShowData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: I am using button click event, and I guess it is also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a short cut, Hope this will help others too...

```
        int row = dgShowData.CurrentCell.RowNumber;

        txtNameEdit.Text = string.Format("{0}", dgShowData[row, 0]);
        txtNickNameEdit.Text = string.Format("{0}", dgShowData[row, 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve cell value then try the code below :

```
private void dgShowData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    DataGridRow row = GetSelectedRow(dgShowData);
    int index = dgShowData.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
    DataGridCell columnCell = GetCell(dgShowData,row, index);
    TextBlock c = (TextBlock)columnCell.Content;
    txtNameEdit.Text = c.Text;
 }

/// <summary>
        /// Gets the selected row of the DataGrid
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="grid">The DataGrid instance</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DataGridRow GetSelectedRow(this DataGrid grid)
        {
            return (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem);
        }


 /// <summary>
        /// Gets the specified cell of the DataGrid
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="grid">The DataGrid instance</param>
        /// <param name="row">The row of the cell</param>
        /// <param name="column">The column index of the cell</param>
        /// <returns>A cell of the DataGrid</returns>
        public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
        {
            if (row != null)
            {
                DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

                if (presenter == null)
                {
                    grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
                    presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
                }

                DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);

                return cell;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

## EDIT

For WinForms :

```
DataGridCell currentCell;

string currentCellData;

// Get the current cell.

currentCell = dgShowData.CurrentCell;

// Get the current cell's data.

currentCellData = dgShowData[currentCell.RowNumber,currentCell.ColumnNumber].ToString();

// Set the TextBox's text to that of the current cell.

txtNameEdit.Text = currentCellData;
```

Comment: Creating a Windows CE Application, Winforms

Comment: why you don't change to work with WPF or work with datagridView

Comment: My OS version is Windows 6.1, Latest won't work in the device :(

Comment: I just added a snippet code for WinForms plz try it

Comment: I appretiate your effort, But this is the same I tried, I am getting the current cell value in the textbox. what i need is when i click a row in the datagrid, it should automatically all corresponding textboxes, say i have 2 columns in the datagrid. It is should two textboxes when i click any row in the data grid.. once again thanks for your effort

Comment: it's strange that no one complains about the `GetVisualChild<T>(...)` method? I doubt it is not a standard method (already searched in Object Browser window and Google, the result is just the `GetVisualChild(int index)` (no generic and the argument is some index). So please post the code for that method.

Comment: You can find it here :  http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html

Comment: @MoezRebai : It was quite simple, we wasted our time!

Comment: Glad 4 u you found it but really i misunderstand you question maybe the way u asked it was a little bit unclear :)